# How to reference a class with a use statement?

Tags: coding-standards

Inside a function in a controller class, I have the following:

```
$form_state = new \Drupal\Core\Form\FormState();
```

It works, and produces a new instance of a FormState.

Codesniffer is not happy with this, and tells me:

> Namespaced classes/interfaces/traits should be referenced with use statements

So far I've added this use statement:

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
```

which is accepted (i.e. it does not break anything).

However, I am unable to figure out what to use to use to produce a new instance of a FormState, that Codesniffer will accept.

Comment: This is a PHP programming question, unrelated to Drupal specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need a use statement for the class, not the interface

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormState;
```

and then

```
$form_state = new FormState();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  It is possible to expand the answer with a brief explanation about when to use the use statement for the class and when the interface? (I.e. what is "this case").

Comment: You can't instantiate an interface. You usually use interfaces to either implement a class for an interface or to check whether an object is what you are expecting.